# Jquery add specific if statement

Tags: jquery, twig

Perhaps a strange question! I developer created a jquery/JSON function to load some products!
He is building up the HTML in a way I don't know. I'm trying to add an if statement between the code but I can't get that to work.

Any suggestions?

```
 $.getJSON(url, function(json){
 $.each(json.products, function(index, product){
... some more code ....

  $('<div>').addClass('item-meta-container').append(
    $('<div>').addClass('ratings').append(
      $('<div>').addClass('ratings-result').css('width',+productScore+'px')
      )
     ).append(

// in here I want an if statement //

   ).appendTo(object)
```

This is the only way to do it. So I want to add an if statement like

```
       if(mode == 'list'){
         $('<div>').addClass('product-description').html(product.description).appendTo(productObject);
        }
```

How do you do that?

Comment: This is quite convoluted use of `append` and `appendTo`. What final HTML structure you want to achieve? Being specific, `.product-description` should be child of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read [here](http://api.jquery.com/append/), `append()` expects `Type: htmlString or Element or Array or jQuery`

I think you should build your content (empty or div) and then append it like this:

```
//--- check if mode == 'list' on the outside
var myContent = (mode == 'list') ? $('<div>').addClass('product-description').html(product.description).appendTo(productObject) : "";

$('<div>').addClass('item-meta-container').append(
    $('<div>').addClass('ratings').append(
        $('<div>').addClass('ratings-result').css('width',+productScore+'px')
    )
).append(myContent) //--- Here's your content!
 .appendTo(object);
```

Have a look **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/SZ8zg/1/)** for a simplified example.

Comment: Ok thx for your answer. Is the way the developer build this piece of code a good way to build? I really learnt it differently..

Comment: it depends on what you need to do. Usually I prefer to build manually the string to append (e.g. `<div class='item-meta-container'><div class='ratings'>...</div></div>` rather than let jQuery build and append each div